# MYSQL : Optimize Requests, by making redondant id the index

Tags: mysql

currently the structure of my Table has an Auto increment id.

But the request on the table takes some time since I am requesting another id called "potid" that isn't the Index of the table...

This potid is an id but it can appear in multiple rows with the same potid.

Is there a possibility to make the potid the index, or something that optimize the research instead of the default id

best regards

Comment: Why not? The index is not necessary to be unique.

Comment: @i486 So do I have to remove the deault id? Will I be able to edit  a specific row in phpmyadmin?

Comment: No need to remove default id (suppose it is the primary index). When you have `...WHERE potid=...`, the server will choose to use `potid` index instead of other. How many rows you have in this table?

Comment: 350000 rows in average, is that too much?

Comment: It is normal - the index will help to speed up.

Comment: a query takes about 0.0014 sec, but there can be up to 200 queries every seconds, from all the users browsing my page, Is there a way to optimize my node.js mysql on such big table?